# Different Methods of Copy and Pasting Formulas and Values Across workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste values and formulas from one workbook to another. Is there any way to do this without scanning through each cell individually. I have looked into paste special and realizes that it separates value and formulas, which is understandable, however is there a way for it to do both?

I have tried to use .Value, .Value2, and have read that .Text is not what I need.
I have also tried doing Range().copy Range() to paste it over, and that does not work either. Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub ImportRange(WB As String, WS As String, RngTo As String, Optional RngFrom As String)
    If RngFrom = "" Then
        RngFrom = RngTo
    End If
    Dim i As String

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range(RngTo) = Workbooks(WB).Worksheets(WS).Range(RngFrom)
    'Does nothing

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range(RngTo).Value = Workbooks(WB).Worksheets(WS).Range(RngFrom).Value
    'Does not bring the formula, just leaves new cell blank

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range(RngTo).Value2 = Workbooks(WB).Worksheets(WS).Range(RngFrom).Value2
'    Does not bring the formula, just leaves new cell blank


End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to copy values and formulas? You can always use [`.PasteSpecial`](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-pastespecial-values-formats-formulas-and-more/), see "Pasting Formulas with VBA PasteSpecial".  Edit: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do? How could you copy and paste a value *and* formula on the same cell?  Does `PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas` not paste a value if there's no formula in there?

Comment: It does not seem to be bringing the formulas with it when I use .PasteSpecial x1Paste Formulas, which is a little offputting for me as it means I have messed up somewhere else.

Comment: `xlPasteFormulas`, the letter "l" as in lima, not the number "1".

Comment: Whoops, I fixed that already but the problem is with some hidden unprotected cells in my document. It works when the cells are unhidden, but I thought that excel could bypass that and grab the formulas when the formulas in the cells are hidden in the protection section of format cells. Apparently I was wrong and it only brings over blanks.

Comment: Use your macro to turn protection off when it starts, and back on when you're done

Comment: I was trying to do all of this without calling my two functions for protecting and unprotecting the workbook because they are password protected and not everyone has it. I guess I will just have to unhide the formulas for everyone, I was just trying to make the spreadsheet look less cluttered. Thank you all for the help!